# Android LocationListener.onLocationChanged is NEVER called

Tags: android

I've got a strange problem and have spent to many minutes now trying to figure this out. for my NFC Checkin app in the Android Market, I am accessing the location of the user to do a Foursquare search.

So, here's roughly what I do (similar code has worked before - but now I am on a a Galaxy Nexus and still on Android 4.0.2):

```
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_MEDIUM);

        String providerName = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


        Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providerName);

        showSearchUI();
        if (loc.getTime() > (new Date().getTime() - 1000*2*60)) //2Minutes back
        {
            Log.d("demo", "LastKnownLocation is good enough, using this location!");
            startVenueSearch(loc);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("demo", "Requesting network location updates...");
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(providerName, 0, 0, this);
        }
```

The activity implements the LocationListener interface, so here is the onLocationChanged method:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    Log.d("demo", "Got fresh location, beginning... " + location.getLatitude() + " / " + location.getLongitude());
    //fake hybris
    //location.setLatitude(48.150098d);
    //location.setLongitude(11.546026d);

    startVenueSearch(location);

}
```

Problem: I simply get no location updates. I just hacked around and changed the code from a direct call to the NetworkProvider to the criteria-based search for a provider, but it still won't work. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

`@Override` may be a problem since `LocationListener` is now an interface. Try using

```
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Toast("onLocationChanged");
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast("onProviderDisabled");
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast("onProviderEnabled");         
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Toast("onStatusChanged");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are hitting your first if condition every time you will not be calling requestLocationUpdates. This is what registers your listener and causes you to get location updates. Make sure to register for updates in both methods or just extract it so it gets called regardless of which condition is met